# How can I write it as a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I found this functional component example over internet. 
How can I write it as a class component. I have lost in parameters.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from '../_helpers/auth'


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => {

            if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
                return <Component {...props} />
            } else {
                return <Redirect to={
                    {
                        pathname: '/public',
                        state:
                        {
                            from: this.props.location
                        }
                    }} />
            }
        }}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: The argument are just `props`, you are just destructing component and renaming it.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a class component? Also that `this.props.location` part doesn't seem right

Comment: I don't. Just trying to learn either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the `PrivateRoute` functional component as a class by doing the following:

```
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={props => {

        if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
          return <Component {...props} />
        } else {
          return <Redirect to={
            {
              pathname: '/public',
              state:
              {
                from: props.location
              }
            }} />
        }
      }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see etarhan has already provided correct answer, but I just want to mention something about making your code cleaner, and thus, more maintainable and readable. Please, I highly recommend separating your logic you have.

I see you wrote above:

> I have lost in parameters.

And I'm not surprised. I was lost too! I would recommend separating the logic out a bit more. Also you do not need and `else` statement return as if it's not the first `if` it **has** to be the else, so we can just return what in the `else` block. So this is how I separated your code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import auth from '../_helpers/auth';

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  getComponent = () => {
    const { component: Component, location } = this.props;

    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <Component {...this.props} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: '/public',
          state: {
            from: location,
          },
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={this.getComponent()} />
    );
  }
}
```

As Robert C. Martin stated in his book Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (highly recommend).

> “Clean code is code that has been taken care of. Someone has taken the
>   time to keep it simple and orderly. They have paid appropriate
>   attention to details. They have cared.”